# What is the best case to use the commit docker command?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

The Docker platform contains the **`commit`** command.

This command can create an image by a container, when I read this in official guide I think to commit database container with data but this option is not supported.

My question is:
What is the best case to use the commit docker command?

Comment: It can be confusing, it's not really the same as a git commit, since you aren't actually committing the project files, essentially only what is specified in the Dockerfile itself. For example, let's say I need apache running on ubuntu, if that doesn't already exist, I might create a new dockerfile that pulls in from an existing ubuntu image, then I'll write out the configuration to setup apache. I can then commit/push this image to docker hub for use in future projects, or to share with the community for others to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure there is a "best case", but I'll try to answer anyway.

Commiting can be very useful when a container needs to be built quickly, since writing Dockerfiles is usually more time consuming than just building a container from "within". Commits enable you to share a container between machines (usually via a [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)).

As for your sentence ...

> I think to commit database container with data but this option is not supported.

That's not quite true, you can indeed commit a database's data in a container. I guess you have your DB data in a volume mount, though:

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.
>
> – [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description)

So, instead of having your DB data in a volume mount, which stores the data on the host and not the container, you *could* have your DB data in a directory owned by the container instead of the host. Then, the data would be included in the commit.

Comment: If I have a web application who write info in xml file and this application run in a container. When I commit the container the change to xml file is committed ?

Comment: Yes, unless the XML file resides in a volume mount.

Comment: if I create an image by a folder with php file and xml for configuration ? My idea is to change setting wich Db connection directly from a container

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "by a folder with php file and xml for configuration". Can you clarify please?

Comment: My idea is to change setting wich Db connection directly from a container

Comment: Yes, sure, you can have a folder in the container and the XML can be in that folder. Since your configuration settings for the database are in that XML, and you commit both XML and the folder, it's in the container. Hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159347/discussion-between-daniele3004-and-fabian-lauer).